# Proof on the inequality involving matrix splitting and trace operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, vector-spaces

Suppose positive definite matrices $V, B, D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are given, where $D$ only contains diagonal entries of $V$, i.e., $D=diag(V)$, and $X, G\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}$. Could the following be proved:

$$\frac{1}{2}tr((D^{-1}G)^TVD^{-1}G) - 2tr(X^TV(D^{-1}G)) + 2tr((D^{-1}G)^TBX)<0$$

for some arbitrary $G$, or for the case $G=2(VX-BX)$.
I tried to apply the steps from:
[Possible proof for the relation involving matrix trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109943/possible-proof-for-the-relation-involving-matrix-trace)

Comment: @user50601. See Wikipedia: Shur complemet (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) and Matrix Block inversion of positive definite matrices in Jean Gallier Home page (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf )

Comment: Surely this inequality is obtained starting from the trace of a 2x2 or 3x3 matrix whose entries are a function of blocks $D,G,V,X,B$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Elias Thanks for the answer; I'm impressed by your observation. I've downloaded the paper, but would kindly ask you to be more specific. I'm unable to find the way to establish the inequality.

Comment: @Elias Could the above inequality be somehow cast to $$\frac{1}{2}(D^{-1}g)^TVD^{-1}g - 2x^TV(D^{-1}g) + 2(D^{-1}g)^TBx<0$$for $g, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, later with the proof extension to the original inequality with trace involved? If so, I guess the proof could be facilitated (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a better idea. This is not necessarily the answer of your question or proof. But a strategy that works for sure for you to get your proof.

Put $ U = [U_1, U_2, U_3] ^ T $ and
 $$
 L=\begin {pmatrix}
 V & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & V & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & B
 \end {pmatrix}
 $$
 By hipothesis we heve $
 Tr(U^ TLU) \geq 0.
 $
 The difficulty is now set $ U_1 $, $ U_2$ and $U_3$  properly so that
$$
 -Tr(U^TLU) =\frac{1}{2}tr((D^{-1}G)^TVD^{-1}G) - 2tr(X^TV(D^{-1}G)) + 2tr((D^{-1}G)^TBX)
 $$
Now you can use knowledge of quadratic forms to get your proof. That is a lot sitema in which the variables are the building blocks$ U_1 $, $ U_2$ solve (he may have more than one solution) for $ U_1 $, $ U_2$ in terms of $ [D^{-1} g] $ and $ x $.

Comment: @user506901. In my answer is easy to see that $U_1=D^{-1}g$. Good Look.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it's not easy for me to understand your approach. If you have some time, perhaps you could explain your $U=[U_1, U_2, U_3]$ construction (or, simply, give the solution).